# Как запустить параллельно action-ы (actionhero js)

Tags: node.js

У меня есть набор *action*, которые парсят страницы.

Мне надо запустить все параллельно и по завершении получить результат.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm i async

```js
var async = require('async');

async.series([
  function(done) {
    //тут парсите страницу и вызываете done(), первый аргумент это ошибка(true/false), второй это результат 
  },
  function(done) {
    //тут парсите страницу и вызываете done(), первый аргумент это ошибка(true/false), второй это результат 
  },
  function(done) {
    //тут парсите страницу и вызываете done(), первый аргумент это ошибка(true/false), второй это результат 
  }
], function(err, result) {
  console.log(result); // массив
})
```

Comment: Да, спасибо но там есть таски. Именно то что нужно. Задачи